# Ganhar bounty em resposta wiki é correto?

Tags: discussion

Fiz essa [resposta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/a/570/58), e ao fazer, coloquei como *c.w.* justamente para não receber a pontuação, pois nada fiz além de juntar ambas as respostas já existentes (algumas editadas posteriormente). Não recebi nenhuma pontuação pelos votos, mas agora recebi a pontuação da recompensa.

Seria isso correto?

---

I did this [answer](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/a/570/58), I put as C. W. just to not receive a score, for nothing did well to join both existing answers (some later edited). I received no score for the votes, but now I received the reward score.

Would that be correct?

---

[image]

Comment: At any rate C.W. [is not supposed to be used as a reputation denial mechanism](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/227290/stop-using-community-wiki-as-a-reputation-denial-mechanism).

Answer (score 9):

I think what matters here is that the person who asked the question offered some of his own reputation to the answer who better fit: Your answer is a wiki, and gather the best from other answers (with proper crediting).

**It is correct, as intended**. You can see that it is by-design in [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/16065/295117)

> How does Community Wiki mode affect bounties?
>
> Bounties are not affected by community wiki mode. When you award a
>   bounty to an answer marked community wiki, the reputation bonus will
>   be awarded to the user who posted the original revision of the answer.

Related: [Can a community wiki answer win the bounty?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/20931/295117)

So you could think the reputation you gained from the bounty has been well earned.